# NSIS - onClick not working at all

Tags: nsis

I have an issue that is driving me crazy: I cannot get the the onClick to work, not even with a simple example:

I've already read the documentation of NSIS, once and again before asking, but it seems something is stuck (yes I'm new in NSIS).

```
Function button_click
  MessageBox MB_OK "Hi there!"
FunctionEnd

Function fnc_USB_drive_Create
  ...
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 12 74 121 30 "Button1"
  Pop $hCtl_USB_drive_Button1
  ${NSD_OnClick} $hCtl_USB_drive_Button1 button_click
  ...
FunctionEnd
```

The button appears on screen, but clicking it does nothing. It's days that I have been working on this.

I have Win7 SP1 64b, and the NSIS + NSIS dialog designer (latest version of all). Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
page custom fnc_USB_drive_Create
var hCtl_USB_drive_Button1
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Function fnc_USB_drive_Create
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    pop $0
    ${NSD_CreateButton} 12 74 121 30 "Button1"
    Pop $hCtl_USB_drive_Button1
    ${NSD_OnClick} $hCtl_USB_drive_Button1 button_click
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd    
Function button_click
    MessageBox MB_OK "Hi there!"
FunctionEnd
```

Works fine for me, do you have any other code that might be messing up the dialog?

Comment: Hi Anders, yes, I'm using the NSIS Dialog Designer and therefore the modern MUI2.nsh instead of the nsDialogs.nsh

Comment: Hi Anders!!  THANKS, you have been most helpful!!  It seems that the NSIS Dialog Designer, when fill in the onClick field, it will create an empty function. So you where right, onClick worked for everybody (except me).